# Understanding infix behavior in scala

Tags: scala, infix-notation, language-theory

Wasn't sure if I should ask this here or on [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/), but anyway

In Scala it's possible to write method calls using infix syntax, i.e. omitting dots and parens.

As an example you could do this:

```
lst foreach println // equivalent to lst.foreach(println)
```

Naturally one would assume that `lst map _.toString` would be evaluated to `lst.map(_.toString)`, which is equivalent to `lst.map(x$1 => x$1.toString)`

But dropping `lst map _.toString` into the repl yields a surprising result, it's evaluated as `((x$1) => sList.map(x$1.toString))` causing the method call to malfunction.

So why is that? Why is it that the simple rule of `a.f(b)` being equivalent to `a f b` no longer applies when writing `a f _.b`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the expression is ambiguous.

From Scala's (somewhat outdated) spec P94: http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf

> An expression(of syntactic category Expr) may contain embedded underscore symbols `_` at places where identifiers are legal. Such an expression represents an anonymous function where subsequent occurrences of underscores denote successive parameters.

Since `lst map _.toString` is a legal expression, it can naturally be evaluated as an anonymous function like `(x) => lst.map(x.toString)`.

You can still use infix expression by curly brackets that make Scala compiler evaluate placeholder function first.

```
scala> val lst = List(1,2,3,4,5)
lst: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

scala> lst map { _.toString }
res43: List[String] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

Comment: `lst map (_.toString)` is also legal; you don't strictly need curly braces for that